# How to save an image with wsdl / SOAP in PHP?

Tags: php, soap, wsdl

Hello I am trying to retrieve images passed though wsdl as a variable

```
$wsdl = 'http://mydataconnection.com/IR?wsdl'; 
ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", "0"); // TODO: disable WSDL cache if required
ini_set("default_socket_timeout", 10);   // TODO: set appropriate read timeout
$client = new SoapClient($wsdl, array("connection_timeout"=>5)); 

$days = 7;  // Get all products that have changed in the past 7 days
$date = date('d/m/Y 00:00', (time() - ($days * 24 * 60 * 60))); 
$productIds = $client->getProductIdsChangedSinceDateStrForType(array("lastRequestDateStr" => $date, "leafOnly" => true))->getProductIdsChangedSinceDateStrForTypeReturn;


foreach ($productIds as $productId) { 
$product = $client->getProductUsingIdAndImageFlag(array("productId" => $productId, "incImage" => true))->getProductUsingIdAndImageFlagReturn; 

$image =       $product->image; 

}
```

This code returns and number of variables within $product (an array), including the $product->image that returns the whole image but I cannot seem to save the data in a legible format.. the start of the $image data looks like this and is quite long so I will not post all of it...

```
‰PNG  IHDR88@x=€IDATxÚì½|[×Ùø¯3CÌÌÌÌL2³%ÙZK–%Ë’eŒ23sÐa‡“¦M»•×n+­´­k»rõïÈ7ñœ4É¶÷Ýÿó×žïçùœœV$û|ïóœ««+Ôù? þ (*¢B PTE…@ PTŠ @ ¨Š @Q!¢B (*¢B PTE…@ PTŠ @ ¨Š @Q!¢B (*¢B PTE…@ PTŠ @ ¨@Q!¢B (*¢B PTE…@ PTŠ @ ¨@Q!¢B (*¢B PTE…@ ¨Š @ ¨@Q!¢B (*¢B PTE…@ ¨Š @ ¨@Q!¢B (*E…@ PTE…@ ¨Š @ ¨@Q!¢B (*E…@ PTE…@ ¨Š @ ¨@Q!(*¢B (*E…@ PTE…@ ¨Šúÿ ?ýË-EýÿÍÒ
```

I have tried using the code below to save the image, but it does not work and could be the wrong approach.

```
base64_decode($image);
$filename = "$imagename.png";
if (!$handle = fopen($filename, 'w')) {
    echo "Cannot open file ($filename)";
    exit;
}

if (fwrite($handle, $content) === FALSE) {
  echo "Cannot write to file ($filename)";
  exit;
}
fclose($handle);
echo system("png -d $filename");
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I hade a response from my soap client like yours.
In my case the code below works.

```
$image =       $product->image;
$filename = "test.png";
if (!$handle = fopen($filename, 'w')) {
    echo "Cannot open file ($filename)";
    exit;
}
if (fwrite($handle, $image) === FALSE) {
    echo "Cannot write to file ($filename)";
    exit;
}
fclose($handle);
```

Comment: I am also facing issue. Unable to get attachment in SOAP UI. I have different type of files like xls,pdf,png etc. It should be download using SOAP UI. Would appreciate for help.Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Just trying random things to see what happens...

```
header("Content-type: image/png"); // or whatever 
print $image;
```

Will show the image on the screen Im still trying to work out how to save it as afile

Comment: imagepng(imagecreatefromstring($image),$imagename.'.png');